# Qt 4.6.3 Symbian app crashes after few startups when connecting to Internet

Tags: qt, symbian

I develop Qt 4.6.3 Symbian app for Symbian^3 devices with Internet access.

1. What is currently the best way to connect Qt Symbian app to Internet?
   At the moment I use symbian header "sym_iap_util.h", but app for some reason crashes after few startups. Is there any issues when we use this header with qt symbian^3 devices and when IAP query dialog appears on screen. I cannot use QTMobility at the moment because is only Qt 4.6.3 preloaded into device.
2. I have read that -network using apps- might crash (ViewSrv 11) when selecting IAP and while waiting for some longer time in "pre-shared key for WLAN" dialog. What is the workaround for this problem?
3. Is there any issue when we using qApp global variable in Qt Symbian app on device?

I must say that app work fine on emulator but sometimes crashes after 10 or so startups on E7  Nokia device. Following error dialogs appears when app crashes: Application closed: Local-c87f6318 and Application closed: 02603fc85b80baea

Answer (score 0):

How about "QWebView" or "QNetworkAccessManager" ?